# React-Native Project won't build on ios or android

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, development-environment

Im a freelance developer and I've recently took a contract to help a RN app launch; however, I can't for the life of me get  either the android or ios emulators running on my machine.

Here is my react-native version:

```
    "react-native": "0.63.3"
```

steps to reproduce error:
yarn start && yarn ios

here is the error:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-native run-ios
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - rn-fetch-blob (to unlink run: "react-native unlink rn-fetch-blob")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Found Xcode workspace "LoadBetter.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace LoadBetter.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme LoadBetter -destination id=6BB5A9A1-B45E-44F9-BF3D-CC9B962AEE21")
success Successfully built the app
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AF1C64B5-C57A-4859-92F6-127B9514F7F2, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:45BA0E53-29BB-4282-A275-980FD06BDDD5, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A1FCB8D5-6CA1-43BB-9659-5A4C36359C79, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:219F0A9A-A0AC-459D-871E-CB54BDF9AEFA, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5642197F-3A7B-48D8-9068-4D4442C3FE67, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C6AB27A8-5F6C-451B-BBB1-0E55476CB8A6, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:46D25E85-6DEB-4050-AA6F-EBEFD53ADDD7, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:26370E8C-68A8-4435-ACCC-744A52D40962, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:80820DD8-3514-4AF9-9998-8CB935C76030, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C4C1EDC1-79D2-4B3A-BE4E-9A40696DD8D2, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:72F120CA-E060-4C82-BD76-6B49A59E9F27, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:59F1F637-2941-4EFC-BF21-7FCBA9730CD9, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:88E51E74-C858-4D7F-AAB7-C56EC76C6E0A, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5A0768FE-6C07-416E-A672-F712ECECEAD1, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A6169A15-781B-4323-896B-5FFDF5268DCC, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BBBE77A2-21CC-43A3-B7CB-35E60C5CF38A, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
info Installing "/Users/Zobrist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoadBetter-cayzqpevfoqiseaavtgzlqckqvif/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoadBetter.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/Zobrist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoadBetter-cayzqpevfoqiseaavtgzlqckqvif/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoadBetter.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier /Users/Zobrist/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoadBetter-cayzqpevfoqiseaavtgzlqckqvif/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LoadBetter.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:864:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:201:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Zobrist@Roberts-MBP gui %
```

command:
yarn android
output:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
error Command "sndroid" not found. Did you mean "android"?
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Zobrist@Roberts-MBP gui % yarn android
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1674 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
131 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 129 up-to-date
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:21: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.DashboardGrpc;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:22: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.DashboardOuterClass;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/AuthService.java:34: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.AuthGrpc;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/AuthService.java:35: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.AuthOuterClass;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:7: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.AuthOuterClass;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:8: error: package protos does not exist
import protos.DashboardOuterClass;
             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:13: error: package protos.AuthOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResSkillsWrapper(java.util.List<protos.AuthOuterClass.ResSkillWrapper> reply) {
                                                                                                  ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:34: error: package AuthOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResTrailerTypesWrapper(List<AuthOuterClass.ResTrailerTypeWrapper> reply) {
                                                                                            ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:275: error: package protos.AuthOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResRoles(java.util.List<protos.AuthOuterClass.ResRole> reply) {
                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:284: error: package protos.AuthOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResUsers(java.util.List<protos.AuthOuterClass.ResUser> reply) {
                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:293: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashOrganisationShipmentBrackets(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashOrganisationShipmentBracket> reply) {
                                                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:311: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentPercentage(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashOrganisationShipmentPercentage reply) {
                                                                                               ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:320: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashRole(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashRole reply) {
                                                                                 ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:332: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashUser(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashUser reply) {
                                                                                 ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:347: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentDriver(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentDriver reply) {
                                                                                           ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:354: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashCountry(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashCountry reply) {
                                                                                    ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:383: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashTrailerTypesWrapper(List<DashboardOuterClass.ResDashTrailerTypeWrapper> reply) {
                                                                                                ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:404: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashSkillsWrapper(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashSkillWrapper> reply) {
                                                                                                           ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:425: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashOrganisation(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashOrganisation reply) {
                                                                                         ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:449: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashOrganisations(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashOrganisation> reply) {
                                                                                                           ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:459: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashTrailerSizesWrapper(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashTrailerSizeWrapper> reply) {
                                                                                                                 ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:479: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashDates(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashDate> reply) {
                                                                                                   ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:492: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashReviews(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashReview> reply) {
                                                                                                     ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:509: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashFacility(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashFacility reply) {
                                                                                     ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:529: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentItemDetails(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentItemDetails reply) {
                                                                                                ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:539: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentItem(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentItem> reply) {
                                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:565: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentStop(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentStop reply) {
                                                                                         ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:584: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentStops(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentStop> reply) {
                                                                                                           ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:594: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentQuote(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentQuote reply) {
                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:614: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentQuotes(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentQuote> reply) {
                                                                                                            ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:624: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashIssueReply(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashIssueReply reply) {
                                                                                       ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:632: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashIssueReplies(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashIssueReply> reply) {
                                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:641: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentIssue(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentIssue reply) {
                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:657: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentIssues(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentIssue> reply) {
                                                                                                            ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:667: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentStageFiles(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentStageFile> reply) {
                                                                                                                ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:683: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentStage(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentStage reply) {
                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:697: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentStages(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentStage> reply) {
                                                                                                            ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:707: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipmentPayment(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentPayment reply) {
                                                                                            ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:717: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipmentPayments(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipmentPayment> reply) {
                                                                                                              ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:727: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashShipment(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipment reply) {
                                                                                     ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:795: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashShipments(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipment> reply) {
                                                                                                       ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:804: error: package protos.AuthOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResPaymentHistory(protos.AuthOuterClass.ResPaymentHistory reply) {
                                                                                    ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:828: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashDrivers(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashUser> reply) { 
                                                                                                     ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:837: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashChangeDriver(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashChangeDriver reply) {
                                                                                         ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:844: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashRequestLoad(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashRequestLoad reply) {
                                                                                        ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:882: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableArray ConvertResDashLoadRequests(java.util.List<protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashRequestLoad> reply) {
                                                                                                          ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/ConvertResponseUtil.java:891: error: package protos.DashboardOuterClass does not exist
    public static final WritableMap ConvertResDashContactMessage(protos.DashboardOuterClass.ResDashContactMessage reply) {
                                                                                           ^

                                                           ^
  symbol: variable DashboardGrpc
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:149: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipment reply = stub.getLoad(request);
                                   ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:203: error: package DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote.Builder preRequest = DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote.newBuilder()
                                                        ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:203: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote.Builder preRequest = DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote.newBuilder()
                                                                                                 ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:221: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentQuote request = preRequest.build();
                                   ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:227: error: package DashboardGrpc does not exist
                DashboardGrpc.DashboardBlockingStub stub = DashboardGrpc.newBlockingStub(getChannel());
                             ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:227: error: cannot find symbol
                DashboardGrpc.DashboardBlockingStub stub = DashboardGrpc.newBlockingStub(getChannel());
                                                           ^
  symbol: variable DashboardGrpc
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:229: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ResDashShipment reply = stub.bid(request);
                                   ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:249: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentStop request = DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentStop.newBuilder()
                                   ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:249: error: package DashboardOuterClass does not exist
                DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentStop request = DashboardOuterClass.ReqDashShipmentStop.newBuilder()
                                                                                     ^
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:261: error: package DashboardGrpc does not exist
                DashboardGrpc.DashboardBlockingStub stub = DashboardGrpc.newBlockingStub(getChannel());
                             ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/Zobrist/Desktop/Code/work/loadBetter/gui/android/app/src/main/java/com/loadbetter/DashboardService.java:21: error: package protos does not exist
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Zobrist@Roberts-MBP gui %
```

Ive been on google for over 16 hours trying to debug this issue.
Ive commented out flipper in my podfile
ive reinstalled java and checked my path
ive traversed so many version combos -- upgrading and downgrading -- hoping to find the compatible zone.

Im so lost and this is my last attemp.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS**

There above errors can be fixed by

1. Run command `react-native unlink rn-fetch-blob`
2. Add CFBundleIdentifier in info.plist file

```js
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

**Android**

Try run using android studio and if error exist, try changing gradle version and build